# anchoring an image at the bottom of the content area of a flatList in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

For an app i'm working on the designer wants a background image to a scrollview which would be anchored to the bottom of the content area of the scrollview.

So let's say the screen is 500px tall,the scrollview on content is 1000px, the image to display in the background is 200px.

How can i make it so that the background of the flatlist is empty until the user scroll and reveals the bottom 200px of the content of the scrollview.